# How to implement generate and restore workspace in openfin layout manager? Can you give some examples

Tags: layout, openfin

How to implement generate and restore workspace in openfin layout manager? Can you give some examples

Answer (score 2):

OpenFin recently released its 2nd generation of Layouts. You can find out more about how to use them [here](https://developers.openfin.co/docs/layouts-v2-api), including examples to get you started.